# nested logistic regression model

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data, nested-models

I had a dataset that consists of 20000 chess matches. In this dataset, there are columns and variables- such as the players' ratings- that might have an impact on binary data, a white player is more likely to win. To test this hypothesis, my lecturer told me to perform a nested regression model where I could see the effect of each of these variables. Since it's binary data, I thought about making a nested logistic regression model. However, I don't know how to do that and how to do that in python. Can someone please help?

Comment: This question is the same with: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/506308/nested-regression-model I couldn't flag it as dup. since the other one doesn't have an answer too.

Comment: yeah that's also my account, but no one answers.

Comment: You should not reask, but work on your question to make it better!

Comment: @gunes: Such cases you can flag!